# .NET Package Error

Tags: .net, package

I have installed .NET,i try to create a web project and i face error saying package missing, i checked in control panel visual studio modify the missing package is installed now what should i do...[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall VS and then install again?

Comment: yes i did still shows this message

Comment: shall i update the visual studio for higher version vs2015 to vs2017

Comment: now i am trying repair option waiting for it to finish

Comment: I would definitly go with 2017.

Comment: will try it thanks for the help

Comment: visual studio 2017 works update success

Comment: That's great! should i add it as an answer?

Comment: i tried repair option as well but it doesn't work , so yes it will be the best  answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there’s an issue with the installation package you are using. 
I recommend you to uninstall Visual Studio and delete the installation package. Then, search for the latest available update and try with that.

And while you at it, use `Visual Studio 2017` instead of `Visual Studio 2015`. It’s newer and more likely to be complete.